# Pivot filter issue with slicers

Tags: excel, pivot-table, slicers

When there are no slicers present, and I filter a field using the pivot table, the other filters display the subset that is available within that option.

Ex. I have a transaction for multiple years. I filter Year to 2018. Displayable options in the Month field are Jan - Jun, since that is all that is available for this year.

When there are slicers, although I filter (using either slicer or pivot table filter) on Year 2018, Jan - Dec are available (pivot table filter) although there are no records for Sep - Dec.

I understand that with slicers Sep - Dec would be greyed out in the slicer, but I want the pivot table slicer to behave like when there are no slicers and only show me available options.  Is this doable?  I can use Excel 2010 or 2016.

I have tried doing "Right click on Pivot > Display > Uncheck "Show items with no data on rows" or "Show items with no data on columns" (For excel 16)" I can see that the boxes are unchecked and grayed out.  I have also gone to each of the fields and under field settings have I went to "Layout & Print" and ensure that the box labeled "Show Items with No Data" is unchecked. Yet when I filter the pivot where there is only 1 row of data, other rows still show the full data set.

[image: Pivot Options]

Answer (score 0):

### For Excel 2016

---

Pivot: Right click on pivot > Pivot Table Options > `Display` > UnCheck `Show Items with no data on rows` or `Show items with no data on columns`

---

Slicer: Right click on your slicer > `Slicer Settings` > Select `Hide Items With No Data`

1)

[image]

2)

[image]

Comment: Just a note: If I'm not mistaken this has to be done in Excel 2013 or higher. Excel 2010 has no such feature. In that case, opt for customized slicers. Set slicers with no data to a white fill and white text. Or just use Excel 2016 :)

Comment: I believe you are right. I will note that this is ideal for 2016. Or you can consolidate your comment to a more inclusive solution and I will just remove mine :)

Comment: @urdearboy your solution only affects the slicers, not the pivot table filters.  Is there a solution to that?

Comment: Pivot tables have a similar option (hide items with no data)

Comment: @urdearboy No they don't, at least not that I know of, which is why I'm asking.  You are probably thinking about removing old data, which is not the same as displaying only the available subset of the filtered data, per my example in the question.

Comment: Right click on Pivot > Display > Uncheck "Show items with no data on rows" or "Show items with no data on columns" (For excel 16)

Comment: I tried, but this did not work.  Have updated the question to reflect this.  Any other ideas?